# Python: How to write literal \n and \r characters to a csv file with DictWriter?

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

- I am running Windows 10, Python 3.8.1 64-bit, Visual Studio Code.

I have a script that fetches data from and API with a POST request. The data comes in a JSON format, which I first save in a text file. The JSON data includes multiple tables in it, and I have to write every table to a separate csv file. For this, I use DictWriter.

```
import csv
import json

# This is the form of the text coming from the POST request (not actual data but it has nested 
# dictionaries and those inside lists like here in the "Laptop" list):

post_text = """{"electro": 
{
"Laptop": [{"sony": "value1",
        "apple": "value2",
        "asus": "value\n\n\r3"},
        {"sony": "value11",
        "apple": "value22",
        "asus": "value33"},
        {"sony": "HA",
        "apple": "Ha",
        "asus": "HC"}],
"Camera": [{"sony": "value4",
        "samsung": "val\r\nue5",
        "nikon" : "value6"}]
}
}"""

# Open the a text file and write post_text to it:

txt_file = open("test.txt", "w")
txt_file.write(post_text)
txt_file.close()
```

The JSON file (that has the raw text from the API) includes also newline and other escape characters, meaning `\n` and `\r`.

I open the JSON/txt file for writing the data in those csv files:

```
file0 = open("test.txt", encoding="utf-8")
json_data = json.loads(file0.read(), strict=False) # strict = False is needed for accepting the \ -characters
```

I then fetch all keys from the JSON (=dictionary) file:

```
for k, v in json_data['electro'].items():
    tablelist.append(f'{k}')
```

For writing the csv files with the DictWriter I have used the following script:

```
for i in tablelist:
    print("\n", "Now iterating table", i)
    for k, v in json_data["electro"][i][0].items():
        if k not in fieldlist:
            fieldlist.append(f'{k}')
            print(fieldlist)
    with open(i + '_.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline = '') as myfile:
        wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, fieldnames = fieldlist)
        wr.writeheader()
        wr.writerows(json_data["electro"][i])
        fieldlist = []
```

## My question is:

**How do I include newline and other escape characters (specifically \n and \r) into the test.txt file and every csv file I write with DictWriter?** So far I have been unsuccesful and those characters are shown as new lines in Notepad/Excel and I would like them to be literal \n:s and \r:s in the text (strings).

At the moment this program writes the Laptop_csv as:

```
sony,apple,asus
value1,value2,"value


3"
value11,value22,value33
HA,Ha,HC
```

and I would like it to write it as following:

```
sony,apple,asus
value1,value2,value\n\n\r3
value11,value22,value33
HA,Ha,HC
```

Comment: escape `\n` so it become `\\n`, you can use `str.replace` or raw string literal `r'something\n'`

Comment: Well… `"\r\n"` in JSON *means* an actual newline. The CSV preserves that meaning by saving it as an *actual newline*. Semantically they're both identical. If you want to save the characters"\r\n" wherever a newline appeared in your JSON, you're actually changing the semantics. And you'd have to do that by actually doing a `str.replace`.

Comment: @zamir This is not an option, because I don't have permission to modify the text coming from the POST request. I have to keep the text as it is.

Comment: @deceze This is interesting, because my first output file (which I save the raw text from the POST request) includes different variations of those characters, such as `\n`, `\n\n`, `\n\n\n\n`, `\r\n\` and `\r\n\r\n`, but those all disappear in the csv files written with DictWriter, and are interpreted as newlines (=the csv file has extra new lines that cut off the text). Do you know why this happens? I have not been able to reproduce this with the code above, the test.txt file still does not include literal \n:s and \r:s...

Comment: There are simply competing philosophies historically about how to style a newline, as `\n`, as `\r`, or as `\r\n`. I'm not sure at what point either the JSON parser or the CSV writer may collapse a consecutive `\r\n` to a single newline. If you want to figure that out in detail you'll have to do some deep diving, but IMO that doesn't matter all that much.

Answer (score -1):

CSV module doesn't provide a mechanism to do that.

An option colud be scaping values using `repr` function:

```
>>> print('first\nsecond')
first
second
>>> print( repr('first\nsecond') )
'first\nsecond'
```

Comment: But now you also have surrounding quotes. And possibly different quotes depending on the string content. And possible escaped quotes and other escaped characters as part of your string…